# Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having an error and hoping somebody could help and give me some clues what to do with this. I am following Agile development book in a way selectively and while I copied their code, the result is as follow:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

This is what I have in my routes.rb file:

```
get 'admin' => 'admin#index'
controller :sessions do
 get 'login' => :new
 post 'login' => :create
 delete 'logout' => :destroy
end
resources :users
```

In my session_controller:
    skip_before_filter :authorize
    def new
    end

```
def create
 user = User.find_by_name(params[:login_name])
 if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to admin_url
 else
  redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination"
 end
end

def destroy
 session[:user_id] = nil
 redirect_to users_url, notice: "Logged out"
end
```

In my session#new.html.erb :

```
  <% if flash[:alert] %>
  <p id="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
 <% end %>
 <%= form_tag do %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please Log In</legend>
    <div>
      <%= label_tag :login_name, 'Login name:' %>
      <%= text_field_tag :login_name, params[:login_name] %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= label_tag :password, 'Password:' %>
      <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Also I am using has_secure_password and have recently updated to Ruby v 193 and Rails 3.2.8. I am only still learning ROR and therefore will appreciate your help a lot- I have been trying to figure it out myself but I was not able to.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently posting to the same page which the form is on.
Since your view is the `new` action in the `sessions` controller, it is submitting a `POST` to `sessions/new`. Rails is then looking for a `POST` route to `sessions#new`. Since none exists, it's erroring.

However if you look at your routes, you can see you have a `post 'login' => :create` route which actually goes to the `create` action you set up to handle the form submission. Therefore if you submit the form to `/login` the route will nicely POST everything through to the intended action.

To do this, change:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag('/login') do %>
```

Also, I strongly recommend you read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html which will give you a better overview of how rails routing works.

**EDIT:**
I've just seen you're probably resubmitting to /login which then should work...
I think it will still default to submitting to the current action however which is officially sessions/new so can you give my suggestion a go and see if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when running 'rake routes'? Could you copy that?  Also, could you copy the HTML code rendered by the browser of your form?